# Breeze EF as a design tool

Tags: breeze

I have a list of model classes, but I have only configured fewer classes in the metadata-only DbContext class, when it comes to generate metadata, it actually generates for all the classes, how does that happen, I couldn't work out, please help, thanks in advance and Merry Christmas!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze uses the DbContext's CSDL ( part of the EntityFramework MetadataWorkspace) to generate its metadata.  So basically, the Entity Framework has performed reflection on your classes. The EF documentation should give more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jay! I try to implement the same way as the NorthwindDtoContext class in the DocCode sample, avoid using EF to generate the metadata. You are right, I think EF still generates the metadata, do you know how to avoid that? I must have missed some implementations. Thanks

Comment: You absolutely DO NOT have to expose your entire server-side model. You don't have to resort to DTOs either. Look at the [`DocCode.NorthwindContext`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode.DataAccess.EF/NorthwindContext.cs). It describes a **portion** of a much larger model. The size of the model is determined by the number of `DbSet`s you expose, not the number of classes. You can easily "cauterize" a model by telling EF to ignore specific types. It's worth learning more EF to see how this is done.

Comment: Hi Ward, I have only exposed a fewer DbSets, but it still generates the metadata for all the classes, that is why I don't understand how can it happen. Thanks

Comment: It is all good now! I figured out what had happened, I included a class that references some classes and those classes have their references too. Thanks a lot! Cheers